# What are the settings required for Cucumber to generate output in a JAVA Project?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I just set up a JAVA project ,which has a few very basic features which involve just some print statements.

My CucumberRunner class's code is:

```
package com.check.cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
        format={"pretty","json:output/"},
        features={"src/com/check/features"}
    )
public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

When I run this project as Cucumber features, I get the features are passed in STDOUT but I don't get any JSON output.

I just have 3 files currently in my project: CucumberRunner class, StepDefinition Class and a feature file.(and the requisite jar files)

Do I need to add something to my Build Path to get the output ?

P.S I just started working with cucumber a few hours back.I am very new to it.

Comment: You should try "@CucumberOptions" with removed dot and put a "/" before output

Comment: thanks removing the dot worked

Comment: i postet this as an answer, so please accept it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try "@CucumberOptions" with removed dot